# Getting a component error in Lightning when a user edits Case on detail page

Tags: lightning-experience, case, emailmessage

A user is getting this error every time they try to make an edit on their detail page on a case record:

> [LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error: [Object EmailMessage is not supported in UI API]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue:

[Cannot save Case created via Email-to-case in Lightning if Case Source field is Editable](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCZgQAM)

The workaround, currently, is to remove the `Case Source` field from the page layout for that user or make it read-only on the layout.

The error is due to the fact that Case Source polymorphic field has a value related to `EmailMessage` (and it's not enabled in UI-API which is used in editing the page).